# reading/writing tiff images C

Tags: c, hex, fopen

im working on tiff images. I shouldnt use any libraries to do so.

```
void copy(char *srcFilename, char *dstFileName)
{
  FILE *fsrc, *fdst;
  char c;

  printf("Inside copy function\n");
  fsrc=fopen(srcFilename, "rb");

  if (fsrc==NULL) 
  {
    printf("Couldn't open file %s for reading.\n", srcFilename);
    exit(0);
  }

  /* Add usual error check */
  fdst=fopen (dstFileName, "w");
  /*Add usual error check */
  for ( ; !feof(fsrc); )
  fputc (fgetc (fsrc), fdst);

  fclose (fsrc);
  fclose (fdst);
}
```

this function should copy a tiff image. It works for small tiff images but when its bigger, the output cannot be shown as tiff and i can see its format being changed(by comparing hexa values)

Comment: What is the question again?

Comment: ah sorry, here it is;"what's wrong with bigger tiffs or this piece of code?"

Comment: When EOF is just reached, `fgetc(fsrc)` will return a special end-of-file marker, defined as the EOF preprocessor symbol (with the value of -1). You must not attempt to write that value into the destination file. Instead, use something like `int c; while ((c = fgetc(fsrc)) != EOF) fputc(c, fdst);`

Comment: but again, im not having problem with small images altough there is this "-1"

Comment: I don't see correlation with your code and the tiff format. Your code is simply implementing a binary copy. Have you tried with an arbitrary file (e.g. zeros from `/dev/zero`, assuming you are on Unix) and different sizes?

Comment: @user4815162342, I think the `!feof` handles the `EOF` return value

Comment: @Dacav checking 3th and 4th bytes to see if its tiff(tiff structure). assume im feeding it with tiffs. i tried different sizes, small size works, biggers dont.

Comment: open the read for binary, but open the write for non-binary?

Comment: @Dacav `feof()` will return true only **after** the EOF has been encountered by a read operation. By that time the `EOF` terminator will have been read from the file, and bogusly written to the destination.

Comment: @PeterMiehle You made my day. Thank you  a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the presented code:

1. It opens the destination file in text mode. Use `fopen(dstFileName, "wb")` instead.
2. When EOF is reached, `fgetc(fsrc)` will return a special end-of-file marker, defined as the EOF preprocessor symbol (with the value of -1). This value must not be written into the destination file. A correct look would be something like: `int c; while ((c = fgetc(fsrc)) != EOF) fputc(c, fdst);`